# WP REST API (wp json) in search endpoint dont return full data

Tags: json, wordpress, api

In WP REST API (wp json) in search endpoint :

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/search?search=searchPhrase&_embed
```

returned data is like:

```
0   
id  5533
title   "example"
url "https://www.example.co…"
type    "post"
subtype "post"
_links  
self    
0   
embeddable  true
href    "https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/5533"
about   
0   
href    "https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post"
collection  
0   
href    "https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/search"
```

and its returned data is not complete like `/posts` endpoint that contain more fields like `content` `excerpt` ,...

What can I do to complete the output data for `/search` endpoint?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution we should use this endpoint which return full data of posts.

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=searchphrase&_embed
```